# BOOTSTRAP FULL CALENDAR EVENTLIMIT: How to show all items by expanding a Day's block instead of in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I've working on a requirement using Bootstrap Full Calendar in which they are asking to limit the number of items shown per day to 5 and adding a "+2 more" type button that, when clicked, shows the additional items. I can do this using native Full Calendar functionality:

```
eventLimit: true,
eventLimitText: "More",
views: {
        month: {
                eventLimit: 5,
               }
        },
```

This results in showing only 5 items in any given day. If that day has more than 5 itmes, it will show a "+ * More" button that, when click, shows all of that days items in a popup modal.

That gets me most of the way there. If only it were that easy.

The specific requirements don't want a popup modal. They want that day's block to expand and show all the items inside it instead of the popup.

I haven't yet found a way to do that using the native functionality. I see that I can customize the functionality of the MORE button click by using:

```
eventLimitClick: function () {
```

I've tried to find a way to perhaps change 'eventLimit: true,' to 'eventLimit: false,' on the button click, but haven't had success yet. This still wouldn't get me all the way there because the requirement is asking for just that day's items to expand. Even if I could change to 'eventLimit: false,', that would then show all items for all days. This is a secondary concern and might be acceptable if I can't find a way around it.

I've also messed with trying to add an expand/contract button in the block with the PREV/NEXT buttons that, in theory, might toggle eventLimit: true,/eventLimit: false,. I haven't yet succeeded this either.

Hopefully this is enough information to stage my need. I'll gladly answer more questions if needed.

Anyone have any idea how I can use the native functionality to meet this requirement, or if not, how I might approach some custom JS to achieve this goal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's impossible. Adjust the requirements...surely it's not a deal breaker

Comment: The more I dig, the more I'm coming to that same conclusion. Your confirmation of this, ADyson, will help me make my case.

Thanks